# Product.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, associations, sequelize-cli

i started to use the models/index file that squeli-cli generate   and now this is generateing me a error in the asociations

my model product  my product can belog to many categories:

```js
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Product extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Product.belongsTo(models.ProductType,{as:'family',foreignKey:'product_family'});
    }                                   
  };

  Product.init({

    id:{
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate:{
          isAlphanumeric: true
      }
    },
    price:{
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      allowNull: false,
      validate:{
        len: [0.1,10_000],
        isEven(value) {
          if (value <= 0.1) {
            throw new Error('price must be 0.2$ or higher');
          }
        }
      }
    },
    product_code:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique:true,
      allowNull: false,
      validate:{
        isAlphanumeric: true,
      }
    },
    product_quantity:{
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      validate:{
          isNumeric: true,
          len: [1,1_000_000_000],
          isEven(value) {
            if (value <= 0) {
              throw new Error('quantity must be 1 or higher');
            }
          }
      }
    },
    notification: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      // allowNull defaults to true
    },
  }, {sequelize,modelName: 'Product',});

  return Product;
};
```

my product types model  this model havemany products:

```js
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class ProductType extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      ProductType.hasMany(models.Product, {as:'ProductType', foreignKey:'product_family'});
    }
  };

  ProductType.init({

    id:{
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate:{
          isAlphanumeric: true
      }
    },
  }, { sequelize,modelName: 'product_Type',});

  return ProductType;
};
```

and this is my  models/index

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);

//config 
const config = require('../config/database');

//declaracion de objeto db
const db = {};

//inicializar la conexion
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database,config.username,config.password,{
  host: config.host,
  dialect: config.dialect,
});


fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    
    //cada modelo del directorio lo vinculamos a db
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

  //realizar las asociaciones  de los modelos 
Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

and y got this error
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mdZP.png)

how can i solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named the model `ProductType` as `product_Type` but you're trying to access it by using `models.ProductType` instead of `models.product_Type`.